# Setting the session on click of a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, onclick

I want to set a session variable on click of a Button. But without clicking that button the session variable is set.

What is wrong in my code? Please help..!!

My script is -

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next").click(function(){
    <? $_SESSION["s_id"]=mt_rand(); ?>
    location.reload();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: View the HTML source produced to get an idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

PHP gets executed before you see the site. If this js gets rendered, php is already done with its work and wont do any more. If you want to set a session with a click on a div, you have to create a form and use $_POST to send the request back to the server.

Remember: You can NEVER execute php code like this in javascript. javascript is clientside, while php is serverside.

Comment: If that's true(php code don't execute in javascript), then how my session variable is set, because this random function is executing and variable is set. Please tell.

Comment: Look: This file is on the server. When you ask for it (youre the client) its send through the php-parser which is ONLY on the server. Hes looking for all "<?php ?>" in this file and executes that. He ignores EVERYTHING around it, he dont even know what it is. The parser genereates html-code and send this to you. If you have this page, PHP does nothing more because it did his job. Look into your html page (rightclick -> View source) and you will see what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables need to be set before a document outputs any data. You could possibly use an AJAX call to allow the session to be set in an external file on button press.